# Box input for Administrator password with secure string

Tags: powershell, plaintext, securestring

Need little help , 
i need to create a Input Box that user your enter new Local Administrator Password .
very simple , so i wrote this script but it does not work , 
can you help me ?

```
$pass = Read-Host "Enter Password" -AsSecureString 

net user administrator $pass
```

Comment: you need to _un_-secure-string the secure string ... [*grin*] this otta do it >>> `[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Pass))` <<<

Answer (score 0):

What `Read-Host -AsSecureString` returns is an instance of [`System.Security.SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring), which by design cannot be used as *plain text*.

You can *force* its re-conversion to plain text as follows, but note that **the very point of using a secure string is to *avoid* plain-text representations.

Given that calling *external programs* such as `net user` *requires* a plain-text representation, it's more secure to use *.NET* alternatives that can work directly with `SecureString` instances**, if available.

If you must use `net.exe`, use the following:

```
# Read the password masked, into a SecureString instance.
$passSecure = Read-Host "Enter Password" -AsSecureString

# INSECURE: Force reconversion to plain text.
$passPlainText = [pscredential]::new('dummy', $pass).GetNetworkCredential().Password

# INSECURE: Pass the plain-text representation to `net user`
net user administrator $passPlainText
```